# ListBox bound to collection does not automatically refresh. Why?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a ListBox which is bound to a collection. When I add an item to the collection I see no change in the ListBox.

However, when I resize the window a little, then the new item suddenly appears in the ListBox. So the binding seems to be working, just the refresh is missing.

What might I be doing wrong here?

XAML:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Name="TestModules" ItemsSource="{Binding ModuleList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TE}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="-"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AF}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Code:

```
    private List<PruefModule> _moduleList = new List<PruefModule>();
    public ICollectionView ModuleList { get; private set; }

    ModuleList = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_moduleList);
    _moduleList.Add((PruefModule)ModulesGrid.SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) instead of the ICollectionView and it should work ok.

From MSDN:

> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when
>   items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

like Adrian said you should use ObservableCollection.

nevertheless you can call Refresh after adding a item.

```
 _moduleList.Add((PruefModule)ModulesGrid.SelectedItem);
 ModuleList.Refresh();
```